# filter the objects with array using ES6

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter, ecmascript-6

**How to find the length of the ARRAY using ES6:**

```
var x = [{a:"apple", b:"Baloon"},{a:"elephant", b:"dog"}];

var results = x.filter(aValue => aValue.length > 3);

console.log(results);
```

Note:
aValue.length would have worked if this is individual list of array. However, since these are **values assigned to properties. Ex; a: apple**, diff approach required.

**What's the correct code that I need to replace *"aValue.length"* to find the length of the value greater than 3, so the answer would be apple, baloon and elephant ?**

Answer (score 5):

This will work for your needs

```
var results = x.filter(val => Object.keys(val).length > 3)
```

The `Object.keys()` method returns an array of all the keys contained in your object.

Comment: this is not an object. this an array. Have u had a chance to run the code using your solution ?

Comment: It's an array of objects. Yes, the solution works, it grabs the `Object.keys()` of each object inside of your array. What trouble are you running into?

Answer (score 2):

Objects do not have a **length** property. But there is a little trick with which you can have the number of keys of an object.

There are 2 methods that can be used. **Object.getOwnPropertyNames(val).length** and **Object.keys(val).length**

However, there is a little difference between the two. **Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a)** returns all own properties of the object a. **Object.keys(a)** returns all enumerable own properties.